# Android:Saving Fragment State/contents of each views in each Fragment when using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I really,really need a serious help over here. 
I am creating an android app which uses `PagerAdapter` to create `Fragments` in an `activity`. Different Fragment consists of different views according to need which are created during run time. In the last fragment, I have created a sort of `"Submit button"`, which when clicked, is supposed to get user entered values from each views(like `EditText`) from all Fragments.

I am using following command to get the views(int the above mentioned button `clicklistener`):

```
EditText e = (EditText) (getActivity().findViewById(i));
```

But its not geting the view with that ID except of last two fragments. 
So, I am assuming that, it is saving the state of only last two fragments in that activity. 
So, How can I save the `'view states'` of all the fragments in the activity??

And Isn't it so that, when a view is created in a Fragment, and is added in its layout , that view is also added in the main activity layout?? Am I understanding it in the wrong way??Please let me know.

To simplify it, my question is:

How can we save the contents, entered by users, in dynamically created EditText in Fragments, created using the ViewPager (So that it can be accessed later)??

Answer (score 0):

When you add a fragment to a FragmentPagerAdapter (assuming you haven't written a custom pager) it is added to the FragmentManager. The Fragment manager is independent of the activity lifecycle so it retains the fragment state.

If you take a look here: http://code.google.com/p/ratebeerforandroid/source/browse/trunk/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock/library/src/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java?spec=svn42&r=42

You can get an idea of how it works. If you want to save the fragment state for another session you'll need to pull back each fragment (getItem) and either use the onSaveInstanceState or write your own custom function

Hope that helps